# How to write SQL Query to Union/Join/or Pivot Data into columns from two identical tables based on two key columns in both tables?

Tags: sql, hive, pivot

I have two tables called Old_User_Info and New_User_Info. I need to display data on the screen by either joining or Union or they way of Pivoting so they are shown as one row in the output e.g.

Table User_Info_Old:

```
UserID: 1
UserName: Jon Doe
Address: 2030 Pen St
Phone: 999-111-0990
```

Table User_Info_New:

```
UserID: 1
UserName: Jon Doe
Address: 1090 Heming Ln
Phone: 809-290-8765
```

Desired Output:

```
UserID  UserName  Old_Address  New_Address    Old_Phone    New_Phone

1       Jon Doe   2030 Pen St  1090 Heming Ln 999-111-0990 809-290-8765 
2       Jane Doe  909 Kit Ln   7677 Hawk st   876-990-3232 980-322-3333
..
```

and so on for the rest of the records per line old and new data next to one another in columns.

I am new to use Pivot functionality but I believe it will require some other functionality such as Partition may Be?

I have tried to select the columns from one table and then Union All with Second Table. I have an outer Select that will select the final columns but I think I am missing something.

```
SElect * from 
(
select a.userid, a.username, a.Address as Old_Address, a.phone as Old_Phone
from User_Info_Old a

Union All

SElect b.userid, b.username, b.Address as New_Address, b.phone as New_Phone
from User_Info_New b
)as sub
sort by UserID
```

Desired OUtput:

```
UserID    UserName  Old_Address  New_Address    Old_Phone    New_Phone
1         Jon Doe   2030 Pen St  1090 Heming Ln 999-111-0990 809-290-8765
2         Jane Doe  909 Kit Ln   7677 Hawk st   876-990-3232 980-322-3333
```

But the Actual Output is below which is not what I want:

```
UserID         UserName       Old_Address       Old_Phone
1              Jon Doe        2030 Pen St       809-290-8765
Jon Doe        Jon Doe        999-111-0990      809-290-8765
```

Here is my actual Query that I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SEC.MeasureKey as Secondary_Measure_Key, SEC.Subkey as Secondary_Subkey, SEC.MeasureName as Secondary_Measure_Name, if(ISNull(PRI.Denom), Null,PRI.Denom) as Primary_Denom, 
if(ISNull(PRI.Num), Null,PRI.Num) as Primary_Num, if(ISNull(PRI.Rate), Null,PRI.Rate) as Primary_Rate,  if(ISNull(PRI.Contra), Null,PRI.Contra) as Primary_Contraindications, 
SEC.Denom as Secondary_DENOM, SEC.Num as Secondary_NUM, SEC.Rate as Secondary_Rate, 
SEC.Contra as Secondary_Contraindications, PRI.Population as Primary_Population, PRI.flowchart as Primary_flowchart, SEC.population as Secondary_Population, SEC.flowchart as Secondary_Flowchart, 
SEC.MeasureKey + '.' + SEC.Subkey as VLOOKUP 
From
(SELECT --returned 0 rows
DF3.flowchart_name as Flowchart,
DF3.population_name as Population,
Replace(DF3.measure_key,"19","") as MeasureKey, 
DF3.measure_short_name as MeasureName, 
DF3.submeasure_key as Subkey,
DF3.denominator as Denom,
DF3.numerator as Num,
DF3.contraindications as Contra,
DF3.rate as Rate

From DF3_MNR_PRD.Rate_Summary DF3
where DF3.date = '20190217') SEC

LEFT JOIN
(Select
DF2.flowchart_name as Flowchart,
DF2.population_name as Population,
Replace(DF2.measure_key,"18","") as MeasureKey, 
DF2.measure_short_name as MeasureName, 
DF2.submeasure_key as Subkey,
DF2.denominator as Denom,
DF2.numerator as Num,
DF2.contraindications as Contra,
DF2.rate as Rate

From DF2_MNR_PRD.Rate_Summary DF2
where DF2.date = '20180320') PRI

On SEC.MeasureKey = PRI.MeasureKey
and SEC.Subkey = PRI.Subkey

where SEC.Population = 'H4527_MCR-ALL_369'
and PRI.Population = 'H4527 MCR-ALL 369'
and SEC.Flowchart = 'PROD_MR_2019_2RUN1_FCR_02152019004120'
and PRI.Flowchart = 'PROD_MR_2018_MAR_3SDS2_FCR_03192018214442'

order by Secondary_Measure_Key, Secondary_Subkey
```

Comment: I think you do not need Pivot. If someone does not have new information in new_table, do you want the new_address or numbers to be NULL or you only want to include the rows which have new information?

Comment: Is that possible if someone has two or more new addresses or numbers in the new_table?

Comment: Yes, if new information is not present in new_table then the data could be NULL. No, there will be one new address in the new_table for that Key combination based on two columns (ID and Name).

Comment: I am revisiting this query as we are seeing some drops in data where there is no match on the key column, those rows are not coming through even though it is a left join. I suspect that the old table has NULL values so that is why these rows are getting excluded, so it goes back to your orginal comment/question you asked if new table doesn't have matching rows and have Null then we should also include them. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need one 'left join':

```
select 
    a.userid, a.username, 
    a.Address as Old_Address, b.Address as New_Address, 
    a.phone as Old_Phone, b.phone as New_Phone
from User_Info_Old a
left join User_Info_New b
on a.userid = b.userid
and a.username = b.username
```

Let me know if you meet the errors.

Comment: I think it worked. Let me do some more analysis and get back to you. I also need to add couple of filters in the query to only select rows based on matching filters from OldTable and New Table. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @Riz Please accept the answer later if you think the answer worked for you. There is one [check] button under [Vote up or down].

Comment: Hi Gen, can you revisit the query I pasted today please read my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: @Riz could you build some testing data with ‘null’ or some exceptions? Add them into the question so that  I do not need to guess.